# How to check what value a function will return

Tags: python

`print('Hello world!')`. I have problem with a game I am making. The problem is that I have a function that returns a value if a certain thing happened, but I have no idea how to check whether it is going to return a value I need or `None`, so here is a tiny bit of my program:

```
def checking_for_events():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
            #some irrelevant code where I get the multiplier
            background_size = background_size * multiplier
            player_size = player_size * multipler
            return background_size, player_size

#a couple lines later

while True:
    background_size, player_size = checking_for_events()
```

So the first way around its all fine, but when the loop repeats and the function gets called again, it
returns `None`, as the change needed to trigger `if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:` doesn't occur, so `background/player_size` gets changed to `None`, which makes the program break. So I wonder if there is a way to check whether `checking_for_events()` is going to return `None` or the 2 integers that I need, and a way to make sure that `background/player_size` won't get changed to `None`.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track. Why not check the result of `checking_for_events()` first before you try to unpack the result into `background_size` and `player_size`?

Comment: There's no way other code can predict ahead of time what value a function is going to return — in fact, it might cause an exception and not return at all…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't tell what something is *going* to do, only what it actually has done.

Assign the result to another variable. Check if the value is `None` before assigning to `background_size` and `player_size`.

```
while True:
    result = checking_for_events()
    if result is not None
        background_size, player_size = result
```